# Dagger and Login Credentials

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Im looking in a way to create a Dagger2 component to store UserCredentials after password validation

i have 3 activities -> Login, Home, About

i want to create a LoggedUser component after password validation at Login and than @Inject this UserLogged at Home and About, im trying to avoid multiple database access (my case ask for it) and than when user click close Home or About activity, it return to Login and destroy the UserLogged and than restart the process, but im a little bit lost how to create a Custom Component for @ActivityScope to be created at Login but destroyed at Login too

Curreclty im using Kotlin + MVP and Injecting Field at **presenter** in this way:

```
init {
        println("Presenter Init: " + javaClass.simpleName)
        MyApplicationCloudant.getAppComponent().inject(this)
}
```

the component is build in this way:

```
component = DaggerAndroidComponent.builder()
                .androidModule(AndroidModule(this))
                .build()
```

my AndroidModule:

```
@Module class AndroidModule(private val application: PontotelApplicationCloudant) {

    /**
     * Allow the application context to be injected but require that it be annotated with
     * [@Annotation][ForApplication] to explicitly differentiate it from an activity context.
     */
    @Provides @Singleton
//    @ForApplication
    fun provideApplicationContext(): Application {
        return application
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    fun provideLocationManager(): LocationManager {
        return application.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    }

....

}
```

my AndroidComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidModule::class))
interface AndroidComponent {

    fun inject(application: MyApplicationCloudant)
    fun inject(loginPresenter: loginPresenter)
    fun inject(homePresenter: HomePresenter)
    fun inject(aboutPresenter: aboutPresenter)
}
```

Comment: This is a good article about how a `@UserScope` could work: http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/

Comment: @DavidMedenjak i will take a look, thank you